# SSIS Validate file rows before Import

Tags: ssis

I am trying to import a text file into table. The file is in below format.

```
H
RowstobeImported
RowstobeImported
RowstobeImported
T0003
```

The trailer record has count of rows to be imported, less the header and trailer rows. I want to validate if the actual file row count and row count value in trailer record (0003) match. If it matches, then I want to start importing it into table.

Comment: Isn't this same answer or very similar? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17586697/1692632

Comment: Write a script task.

Comment: I am new to SSIS. It would be better if i get step by step point to achieve this.

Comment: http://suneethasdiary.wordpress.com/2011/04/27/trailer-record-in-flat-file/ please refer this link. Nice Explanation.